# how to insert utf-8 format in database with latin collation and table with utf8 collation

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

how to insert utf-8 format in database with latin collation and table with utf8 collation?!

I want to insert to some of wordpress database tables from my own php file , but it's not working,
if I change the databsae collation into utf8_general_ci it's working , I don't want to change the database collation , wordpress it self working with that and it doesn't have any problem,
سلام -> ؟؟؟؟

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

before you do any inserts.

Comment: is mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); doing the same?!

Comment: It's the same, but somehow `SET NAMES` is not recommended. From the manual: This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended. See the MySQL character set concepts section for more information.